# Is there any way to initialize a class without calling the class itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

What I mean is that, is there a way to initialize my own class alike how strings or lists are initialized?

```
>>> a = []
>>> a
[]
>>> b = ""
>>> b
''
```

Is it possible to make this possible:

```
>>> my_class_instance = |1, 2, 3|
>>> my_class_instance
|1, 2, 3|
>>> my_class2_instance = +Hello World!+
>>> my_class2_instance
+Hello World+
```

More curious if this is possible rather than actual implementation.

Comment: You mean is there a way to create your own literal syntax?

Comment: I think I know what you are asking. And the key point is that maybe the istance `[]` or `[1, 2, 3]` is actually an instance of a class. Hope you understand what I am saying.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do that. You are asking how to alter the syntax of python itself.